# maximum estimator method more known as MLE of a uniform distribution

Tags: statistics

Let  $ X_1, ... X_n $ a sample of independent random variables with uniform distribution $(0,$$
\theta 
$$
) $
Find a $ $$
\widehat\theta 
$$
 $ estimator for theta using the maximun estimator method more known as MLE

Comment: If you want to find the maximum likelihood estimate, you first need to derive the likelihood. Did you get that far? Here is a primer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimator

Comment: You asked this question for the method of moments, but you wanted the MLE. I am assuming in that time you've come up with something... surely... what have you tried? What is your effort? I'll write something that will guide you, but I don't want to just write the solution.

Comment: The following video really helped me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XaAtkCzdjLE

Comment: I see no reason why this question is off-topic.

Answer (score 72):

First note that $f\left({\bf x}|\theta\right)=\frac{1}{\theta}$ ,
for $0\leq x\leq\theta$ and $0$ elsewhere.

Let $x_{\left(1\right)}\leq x_{\left(2\right)}\leq\cdots\leq x_{\left(n\right)}$
be the order statistics. Then it is easy to see that the likelihood
function is given by 
$$L\left(\theta|{\bf x}\right) = \prod^n_{i=1}\frac{1}{\theta}=\theta^{-n}\,\,\,\,\,(*)$$
  for $0\leq x_{(1)}$ and $\theta \geq x_{(n)}$ and $0$ elsewhere.
Now taking the derivative of the log Likelihood wrt $\theta$ gives:

$$\frac{\text{d}\ln L\left(\theta|{\bf x}\right)}{\text{d}\theta}=-\frac{n}{\theta}<0.$$
 So we can say that $L\left(\theta|{\bf x}\right)=\theta^{-n}$ is
a decreasing function for $\theta\geq x_{\left(n\right)}.$ Using
this information and (*) we see that $L\left(\theta|{\bf x}\right)$
is maximized at $\theta=x_{\left(n\right)}.$ Hence the maximum likelihood
estimator for $\theta$ is given by $$
\hat{\theta}=x_{\left(n\right)}.$$

Comment: I think you forgot the d theta in the denominator. but good answer! :)

Comment: Thanks aengle...its fixed...:)

Comment: @Nana Very old question, but still. Isn't there a problem with endpoints of the given interval? If they were included you solution would be perfectly fine, but the are not. How do deal with it?

Comment: I have another queston, I got an unbiased $\frac{n+1}{n}X_(n)$, if given that $\theta$ is greater than 1, will the estimator be changed?

Comment: How is differentiating valid here??

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/649678/how-do-you-differentiate-the-likelihood-function-for-the-uniform-distribution-in?rq=1

Comment: @Nana I think the derivative of the log likelihood in this particular case is in fact $- \frac{n^2}{\theta}$ if my calculations are correct. I think you forgot that: $ln(L(\theta | x)) = \sum_{k=1}^n ln((\frac{1}{\theta})^n) = \sum_{k=1}^n -n ln(\theta) = -n^2 ln(\theta)$.

Answer (score 11):

This example is worked out in detail [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-443-statistics-for-applications-fall-2006/lecture-notes/lecture2.pdf) (pages 13-14).

Comment: your link is broken (at least for me...) :p

Comment: @aengle: Thanks, now it works.

Comment: link is dead again

Comment: The link works now, but anyway it's saved in the Web Archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20201111223743/https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-443-statistics-for-applications-fall-2006/lecture-notes/lecture2.pdf